# How do you get the run parameters and runId within Databricks notebook?

Tags: python, databricks

When running a Databricks notebook as a job, you can specify job or run parameters that can be used within the code of the notebook. However, it wasn't clear from documentation how you actually fetch them. I'd like to be able to get all the parameters as well as job id and run id.

Answer (score 18):

## Job/run parameters

When the notebook is run as a job, then any [job parameters](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#run-a-job-with-different-parameters) can be fetched as a dictionary using the `dbutils` package that Databricks automatically provides and imports. Here's the code:

```py
run_parameters = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getCurrentBindings()
```

If the job parameters were `{"foo": "bar"}`, then the result of the code above gives you the dict `{'foo': 'bar'}`.  Note that Databricks only allows job parameter mappings of `str` to `str`, so keys and values will always be strings.

Note that if the notebook is run interactively (not as a job), then the dict will be empty. The `getCurrentBinding()` method also appears to work for getting any active [widget values](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) for the notebook (when run interactively).

## Getting the jobId and runId

To get the `jobId` and `runId` you can get a context json from `dbutils` that contains that information. (Adapted from [databricks forum](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12134/possible-to-get-job-run-id-of-notebook-run-by-dbut.html)):

```py
import json
context_str = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson()
context = json.loads(context_str)
run_id_obj = context.get('currentRunId', {})
run_id = run_id_obj.get('id', None) if run_id_obj else None
job_id = context.get('tags', {}).get('jobId', None)
```

So within the context object, the path of keys for `runId` is `currentRunId > id` and the path of keys to `jobId` is `tags > jobId`.

Comment: py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public java.lang.String com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext.toJson() is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.CommandContext

Comment: @JorgeTovar I assume this is an error you encountered while using the suggested code. What version of Databricks Runtime were you using?

Comment: I've the same problem, but only on a cluster where credential passthrough is enabled. `spark.databricks.passthrough.enabled true`

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you can easily get the parameters from a job through the widget API. This is pretty well described in the official [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#databricks-widget-example) from Databricks. Below, I'll elaborate on the steps you have to take to get there, it is fairly easy.

1. Create or use an existing notebook that has to accept some parameters. We want to know the `job_id` and `run_id`, and let's also add two user-defined parameters `environment` and `animal`.

   ```
    # Get parameters from job
    job_id = dbutils.widgets.get("job_id")
    run_id = dbutils.widgets.get("run_id")
    environment = dbutils.widgets.get("environment")
    animal = dbutils.widgets.get("animal")

    print(job_id)
    print(run_id)    
    print(environment)
    print(animal)
   ```
2. Now let's go to Workflows > Jobs to create a parameterised job. Make sure you select the correct notebook and specify the parameters for the job at the bottom. According to the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#task-parameter-variables), we need to use curly brackets for the parameter values of `job_id` and `run_id`. For the other parameters, we can pick a value ourselves.

[image]

Note: The reason why you are not allowed to get the `job_id` and `run_id` directly from the notebook, is because of security reasons (as you can see from the stack trace when you try to access the attributes of the context). Within a notebook you are in a different context, those parameters live at a "higher" context.

3. Run the job and observe that it outputs something like:

   ```
    dev
    squirrel
    137355915119346
    7492
    Command took 0.09 seconds
   ```
4. You can even set default parameters in the notebook itself, that will be used if you run the notebook or if the notebook is triggered from a job without parameters. This makes testing easier, and allows you to default certain values.

   ```
    # Adding widgets to a notebook
    dbutils.widgets.text("environment", "tst")
    dbutils.widgets.text("animal", "turtle")

    # Removing widgets from a notebook
    dbutils.widgets.remove("environment")
    dbutils.widgets.remove("animal")

    # Or removing all widgets from a notebook
    dbutils.widgets.removeAll()
   ```

5. And last but not least, I tested this on different cluster types, so far I found no limitations. My current settings are:

   ```
    spark.databricks.cluster.profile serverless
    spark.databricks.passthrough.enabled true
    spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation true
    spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages python,sql
   ```

Comment: Hey @Cloudkollektiv is there a way to have these parameters be updated for the next run, say you want the animal:squirrel to be animal:wolf for the next job run is that possible?

Comment: Might be worth looking into dbutils.job.taskValues.set

Comment: this one explains really good way to access the parameters. thanks @Cloudkollektiv