# Databricks Python wheel based on Databricks Workflow. Acces job_id & run_id

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

I'm using Python (as Python wheel application) on **Databricks**.

I deploy & run my jobs using **dbx**.

I defined some **Databricks Workflow** using **Python wheel tasks**.

Everything is working fine, but I'm having issue to extract **"databricks_job_id"** & **"databricks_run_id"** for logging/monitoring purpose.

I'm used to defined **{{job_id}}** & **{{run_id}}** as parameter in "Notebook Task" or other task type, ( see this [How do you get the run parameters and runId within Databricks notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018871/how-do-you-get-the-run-parameters-and-runid-within-databricks-notebook))
but with Python wheel I'm not able to define theses :

With Python wheel task, parameters are basically an array of string :

> ["/dbfs/Shared/dbx/projects/myproject/66655665aac24e748d4e7b28c6f4d624/artifacts/myparameter.yml","/dbfs/Shared/dbx/projects/myproject/66655665aac24e748d4e7b28c6f4d624/artifacts/conf"]

Adding "**{{job_id}}**" & "**{{run_id}}**" in this array doesn't seems to work ...

Do you have any ideas ? Don't want to use any REST API during my workload just to extract theses ids...

Answer (score 1):

Follow below Approach .You will get the Run Id and job id .

> **Approach 1:**

**code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
import base64
import requests
import json
url_list = "https://adb-1090xxxxxxx1.12.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/runs/list"
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer dapia23481xxxxxxx78e7f',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url_list, headers=headers).json()

for job_run in response["runs"]:
    job_id = job_run["job_id"]
    run_id = job_run["run_id"]
    print(f"Job ID: {job_id}, Run ID: {run_id}")
```

[image]

> **Approach 2:**

**Using Log analytics:** If you have configured diagnostic logs in azure databricks , you can use KQL queries to get the JobID and RunID :

```
DatabricksJobs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(48h)
| limit 10
```

For information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907137/how-to-get-the-runid-or-processid-in-azure-databricks#:%7E:text=The%20job%20ID%20is%20the,event%20generation%20for%20the%20stage.) thread by CHEEKATLAPRADEEP.

> **Approach 3:**

First create pass the parameter and define the job or task and Fetch and print the values.

```
print(f"""
  job_id: {dbutils.widgets.get('job_id')}
  run_id: {dbutils.widgets.get('run_id')}
  """)
```

For more info refer this [blog](https://canadiandataguy.medium.com/how-to-get-the-job-id-and-run-id-for-a-databricks-job-b0da484e66f5) by Jitesh Soni